# IOS : Get JSON Response from URL

Tags: ios, json

I am trying to get data from this [link](http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=data&q=mum) and store it in NSArray

Format of the response:

```
data(
[
"Mumbai, MH, India",
"Mumford, NY, United States",
"Mumford, TX, United States",
"Navi Mumbai, MH, India",
"New Mumbai, MH, India"
]
)
```

Tried as like regular JSON response, but not getting any data.

Please help me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your relevant code so people can help you fix it.

Comment: There is a problem with the JSON in the link. Verify by posting the link inside sites like jsonlint.com first.

Comment: can u show the correct data, bz data(
[
"Mumbai, MH, India",
"Mumford, NY, United States",
"Mumford, TX, United States",
"Navi Mumbai, MH, India",
"New Mumbai, MH, India"
]
) this is showing in wrong data

Comment: provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code,

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictionary  = [jsonString JSONValue];
NSLog(@"%@", jsonDictionary);
```

Comment: JSONValue is not a build-in API, use NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 2):

In your php may be return array value. so instead of that use json_encode and Returns the JSON representation of a value.

and use in Objective-C code like

```
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be the problem ..

JSON that have array response will be [x, x, x, x, x]..
But your json is data([x, x, x, x, x]); That's why you are not getting correct response in jsonserialization.

```
NSArray *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

JSON that have dictionary response will be {key=data, key=data, key=data}

```
NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Your json gets the following error when you try to convert

```
(JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
```

Your json not meets both the format. Can you please check it and try

Answer (score 2):

> http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=data&q=mum

This is a JSONP response, which wraps json response in callback function `data`.

Remove `callback` parameter and try to parse again

> http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?q=mum

See also: [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't *look* like JSON to my eyes, but you might be able to pass that input to NSJSONSerializer (I'm thinking the [`JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData%3aoptions%3aerror%3a)) and get an Objective-C object out of it

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code.. this is not perfect.. but you can retrieve the data here.

```
NSError *err = Nil;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=data&q=mum"];
    NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&err];
    NSLog(@"%@",data1);
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",json_string);
    NSString *json = [json_string substringFromIndex:4];
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
    NSCharacterSet *charsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"];
    NSString *json1 = [json stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToTrim];
    NSLog(@"%@",json1);
    if ([json1 length]> 0)
        {
        json1 = [json1 substringToIndex:[json1 length]-2];
    }
    NSLog(@"returnResponse %@",json1);
    NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [a addObject:[json1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
    NSLog(@"%@",a);
    NSLog(@"%@",[a objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your response string meeting JSON qualification JSON string will look like this

```
{
  "array": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
}
```

make sure that response is getting from service is JSON string